# Entity Framework. Resolve Zero Or One to one use one navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Sorry for my English. I have the following entity:

```
public class MediaAlbum
{
    [Key]
    public Guid AlbumId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MediaImage> Images { get; set; }

    public Guid? CoverId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public virtual MediaImage Cover { get; set; }
}

public class MediaImage
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ImageId { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public Guid AlbumId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AlbumId")]
    public virtual MediaAlbum Album { get; set; }
}
```

I need map navigation property **Cover** to Entity 'MediaImage'. 
I tried to solve through fluentApi, but it not worked:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<MediaAlbum>().HasOptional(x => x.Cover).WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ImageId"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MediaAlbum>().HasMany(x => x.Images)
                    .WithRequired(x => x.Album).HasForeignKey(x=>x.AlbumId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MediaAlbum>().HasOptional(x => x.Cover);
    }
```

foreign key is `CoverId` not `ImageId`:

```
public class MediaAlbum
{
    [Key]
    public Guid AlbumId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MediaImage> Images { get; set; }

    public Guid? CoverId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CoverId")]// change to this
    public virtual MediaImage Cover { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MediaAlbum>()
         .HasOptional(x => x.Cover)
         .WithRequired(x => x.Album)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: This is not working: return error: "Invalid column name 'MediaAlbum_AlbumId'